# String from api response cant display break line, but hard code string can display break line

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, line-breaks

Good day,

I am using Angular 8 as my frontend, and java api service as my backend.

I need to retrieve some String from backend, and the String will having `\n` in between, for example:
`"Instructions:\n1. Key in 122<16 digit \nreload pin># to reload.\n2. Press SEND/CALL from`

In my `.ts` file, I am setting this String value as follow:

```
this.str = this.apiRes.responseMsg1;
console.log("this.str : " + this.str);
```

This will give me `Instructions:\n1. Key in 122<16 digit \nreload pin># to reload.\n2. Press SEND/CALL`, thus when I use it to display in html, it will just display as 1 line.

If I hard code this String to a String variable, for example:

```
this.str = "Instructions:\n1. Key in 122<16 digit \nreload pin># to reload.\n2. Press SEND/CALL from";
console.log("this.str : " + this.str);
```

It will give me :

```
Instructions:
1. Key in 122<16 digit 
reload pin># to reload.
2. Press SEND/CALL from
```

Which is what I want.

I am not really familiar with Angular, I am trying to find this answer in google, but cant get any related result.

May I know why is this happen? And any way I can display the api message accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

HTML ignores `\n` line breaks. You basically have two options to fix this:

1. Replace the line breaks with `<br>` elements.
2. Add a line of css `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your HTML element which is displaying your string.